# Joining two tables and replacing values

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table called EnglishText that contains localization strings, along with many other tables (One example would be a Buildings table) that have properties (such as a name, description, etc.) that are keys that map to a English string in the localization table.

EnglishText table
[image: Screenshot of EnglishText table]

The Tag column is the key, with the Text column having the English strings I want.

Buildings table
[image: Screenshot of Buildings table]

Columns such as Name, PrereqTech, and PrereqCivic map to the Tag column in the EnglishText table.

I would like to be able to run a query, such as

```
SELECT * FROM Buildings;
```

with it returning the English text in the Name, PrereqTech, and other fields, rather than the key to the EnglishText table. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you saying that EnglishText table will have rows such as **LOC_BUILDING_MONUMENT_NAME** (the mapping for the 1st row, column name from the Buildings table to the  Englishtext table), and **TECH_BRONZE_WORKING** (the mapping for 3rd row, column PreReqTech from the Buildings table to the English text) etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Each row in the Buildings table has multiple keys that map to strings in the EnglishText table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Assuming/Using:-

[image]

And:-

[image]

Then

**`SELECT Name, _text FROM  Buildings JOIN english_text ON name = _tag`**

results in :-

[image]

Or

**`SELECT * FROM  Buildings JOIN english_text ON name = _tag OR PreReqtech = _tag`**

results in :-

[image]

However, I suspect that you may want a single row per building with all mappings (I suspect that may be possible but may be complex due to the mapping to a single column in the english_text table)

Comment: Thank you for the help! It might just be easier for me to actually replace the keys with the English strings. I was just hoping there would be an easy way to do this without editing them.

Comment: mapping would be beneficial if the texts were used multiple times e.g. the PreReqTech and Civic could perhaps benefit. However, perhaps in separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure you probably want to create a user defined function lookup to turn a tag into the English text. Then apply that function to each of the columns in your select.

Comment: That would work too, it wouldn't be too hard either. I'll probably go this route. Thank you!